# Rails: How to merge two hashes if a specific key has the same value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to merge hashes if a specific key has the same value.

here is the array

```
[{

  id: 77,
  member_phone: "9876543210",
  created_at: "2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z",
  name: "Sure"
},
{
  id: 77,
  member_phone: "123456789",
  created_at: "2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z",
  name: "Sure"
},
{
  id: 78,
  member_phone: "12345",
  created_at: "2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z",
  name: "XYZ"
}]
```

and the required output:

```
[{
  id: 77,
  member_phone: "123456789,9876543210",
  created_at: "2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z",
  name: "Sure"
},
{
  id: 78,
  member_phone: "12345",
  created_at: "2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z",
  name: "XYZ"
}]
```

here's the code I tried:

```
merge_users.group_by { |h1| h1["id"] }.map do |k,v|
  { "id" => k, :member_phone =>  v.map { |h2| h2[:member_phone] }.join(", ") }
end
```

how can I do it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Key values differs member_phone and kitty_member_phone are different.

Comment: @Rajagopalan sorry that was my mistake.

Comment: @JasjeetSingh Yes, I have written the code, Just look at that.

Comment: Thank you. bro really save my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would work for your given example.

code

```
result = arr.group_by {|h| h[:id]}.values.map do |arr|
  arr.reduce do |h1, h2|
    h1.merge(h2) do |k, ov, nv|
      ov.eql?(nv) ? ov : [ov, nv].join(",")
    end
  end
end
```

p result

```
#=>[{:id=>77, :member_phone=>"9876543210,123456789", :created_at=>"2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z", :name=>"Sure"}, {:id=>78, :member_phone=>"12345", :created_at=>"2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z", :name=>"XYZ"}]
```

Comment: Consider using `[ov, nv].join(',')` instead of producing three intermediate instances of string with `ov+","+nv`.

Comment: this code merges every key. and produced a single hash.

Comment: @JasjeetSingh Look at your output, that's what you asked,right?

Comment: @JasjeetSingh This is what your output, `[{
  id: 77,
  member_phone: "123456789,9876543210",
  created_at: "2017-05-03T11:06:03.000Z",
  name: "Sure"
}]`, that's my output as well, where is the difference?

Comment: but it also merges the id with the different value.

Comment: can you please check my hash now?

Comment: @JasjeetSingh Okay, Updated the code now, check it.

Comment: Note that `.values.map do |arr|` can be replaced with `.map do |_,arr|`. That is, you don't need to extract the values before mapping. Also, you want to convert each key-value pair returned by `group_by` to a hash (in an array). That suggests you should look to using `map` rather than `reduce`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Hi, first point is clear, but I don't get your second point, can you please write the code and paste here let me look at that?

Comment: My answer contains code (for using `group_by`) that should give you an idea of what I mean. Let me try to rephrase my point. `group_by` returns a hash. The first key-value pair of that hash (for the simplified array of hashes I used in my answer) is `77=>[{:id=>77, :phone=>"9876543210", :name=>"Sure"}, {:id=>77, :phone=>"123456789", :name=>"Sure"}]`. You want to map that to the hash `{:id=>77, :phone=>"9876543210123456789", :name=>"Sure"}`. (cont.)

Comment: By "map" I mean the latter is a function of the former and depends on no other key-value pairs returned by `group_by`. In mathematical terms that is a 1-1 function, aka 1-1 mapping, which is what the method `Array#map` is. It has the same structure of wanting to convert the array `[1,2,3]` to the array `[1,4,9]`, for which we use `map`: `[1,4,9].map { |x| x*x }`. Each element of the array returned depends only on the corresponding element of `map`'s receiver. So I'm saying whenever you need a 1-1 function, think of the method `map`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland thank you, got it. I will look into your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
grouped = data.group_by do |item|
  item[:id]
end

combined = grouped.map do |_id, hashes|
  hashes.inject({}) do |memo, hash|
    memo.merge(hash)
  end
end
```

It works in two passes:

First group all hashes by the value of the `:id` key
This returns a Hash with the `id` as key, and an array (of all the hashes with this id) as value.

In a second pass all the hashes are merged and mapped to an array again.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  { id: 77, phone: "9876543210", name: "Sure" },
  { id: 77, phone: "123456789", name: "Sure" },
  { id: 78, phone: "12345", name: "XYZ" }
]
```

You could use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to compute the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g) { |_,o,n|
  o.merge(phone: "#{o[:phone]}#{n[:phone]}") } }.values
  #=> [{:id=>77, :phone=>"9876543210123456789", :name=>"Sure"},
  #    {:id=>78, :phone=>"12345", :name=>"XYZ"}]
```

Note that the receiver of [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) is the following.

```
#=> {77=>{:id=>77, :phone=>"9876543210123456789", :name=>"Sure"},
#    78=>{:id=>78, :phone=>"12345", :name=>"XYZ"}}
```

See the doc for `Hash#update` for definitions of the three block variables `_`, `o` and `n`. I used an underscore for the first variable (a valid name for a local variable) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation (a common practice).

Note that `Hash#update` can almost always be used when [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) can be used, and vice-versa.

Here's one way to use `Hash#group_by` here.

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.
    map { |_,a| a.first.merge(phone: a.map { |h| h[:phone] }.join) }
  #=> [{:id=>77, :phone=>"9876543210123456789", :name=>"Sure"},
  #    {:id=>78, :phone=>"12345", :name=>"XYZ"}]
```

Note that

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:id] }
  #=> {77=>[{:id=>77, :phone=>"9876543210", :name=>"Sure"},
  #         {:id=>77, :phone=>"123456789", :name=>"Sure"}],
  #    78=>[{:id=>78, :phone=>"12345", :name=>"XYZ"}]}
```